# How do I run ODBC queries to the iSeries over tables in multiple libraries?

Tags: c#, odbc, ibm-midrange

I need to run an SQL query from a C# program over an iSeries database, where the query contains a subquery over a table in a different library from the tables in the main query.

Previously we were doing this by qualifying the table in the subquery with a library name, however the program has to be run in multiple environments, so no hardcoded library names are allowed in the query string.

To attempt this, I'm putting a DBQ parameter in the connection string with both libraries in it. The [redacted] connection string in full (on separate lines as it's in a .dsn file):

```
DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver
QUERYTIMEOUT=0
PKG=[LIBRARY]/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
LANGUAGEID=ENU
DBQ=,MAINLIB,OTHERLIB
SYSTEM=[IP ADDRESS]
UID={0}
PWD={1}
```

with the UID and PWD substituted in with values from environment specific config files.

According to [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordsservprop.htm) starting the list of libraries in the DBQ parameter with a comma will specify no default library - the first library in the list would otherwise be used for unqualified table names in the query

When I try to run a query with this configuration however, my program returns an ODBCException with the message "[iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0204 - [table name] in [user ID(!)] type *FILE not found".

I have also tried this with "DBQ=*USRLIBL" which is supposed to substitute the user's library list for the parameter.

Does anyone know why, in the absence of a default library, the connection treats the user profile as the default libray, and can anyone suggest how I can get this to work?

Comment: I believe there is a traditional (if perhaps outdated) convention in databases to associate a schema with a user. That is, each user is assigned one namespace that is *owned* by them, and each namespace has one owner; thus it is natural to use the same name for both, and natural for the user's own schema to be the "current" one when no other schema has been specified.

Comment: Also note that the documentation you linked to doesn't mention that the library list (other than the first entry) will be used for unqualified table references, but rather for stored procedure calls and catalog API calls.

Comment: JohnY points to a potential duplicate and WarrenT gives the answer there, i.e., add the NAM=1 attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I did search, but missed that one.

Comment: @JohnY Not exactly outdated. An 'implementation-defined' default schema is part of the current SQL standard (in the absence of a _SET SCHEMA_ statement for the session). DB2 simply sets it the same as the database user. Other implementations may choose a different technique.

Comment: Generally I would make a view over the files.  Simplifies a great deal of things.  I have dealers in one library and parts in another and I always need to see them both together with contacts.